# How do I get Facebook Live mobile app to use the wide angle camera?

Tags: camera, facebook, streaming

Many phones today have more then one camera with many of those having wide angle lens. I'm specifically interested in LG v30+ but it can apply to most modern smartphones now.

How can I get Facebook mobile app to recognise the other rear cameras and use them?

Comment: Have asked elsewhere: [How can you use wide angle on phones that have more then 1 camera? | Facebook Help Community](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=1244166132443950&added&rdrhc) and [Ask Facebook to support wide angle for Facebook Live on LG V30 : lgv30](https://www.reddit.com/r/lgv30/comments/f3i3xs/ask_facebook_to_support_wide_angle_for_facebook/)